# Tkinter: how do i create multiple of row of label and entry box using loop and inputs from user?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

i want to create a simple payroll generator using python tkinter gui. let say the user enter n days in the spinbox, when they press enter it will generate n rows of n day and entry box for user to put working hour.Also how do i get it to display the total hour of n day at the bottom row silmultaneously?

[picture of what ive done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM8KI.png)

[the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrYTG.jpg)

Comment: Start [here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)